# What are the characteristics of Eclipse's release repository?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, p2

As a Eclipse's release repository, like `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-06` or `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03`, what are its characteristics?

As far as I know:

1. Once released, its content will never change;
2. The dependencies in this repository can fully satisfy each other, in other words, when the Eclipse IDE only connects to this site and uses p2 to install and uninstall any features on this site, there are no dependency problems or other problems that cannot be installed or uninstalled

Am I right? Or are there any other characteristics of this repository that are very important?

Comment: I am curious about why you're curious. This might be a better question for https://www.eclipse.org/forums/, as it's not really a programming problem, or wiki pages branching off of https://wiki.eclipse.org/SimRel/Simultaneous_Release_Policy_FAQ, or the right mailing list. The first of your deductions makes sense, the second is more or less confirmed with https://bugs.eclipse.org/370974.

Comment: It's a simultaneous release of more than 65 Eclipse projects and the basic idea is that parts will work with other parts from the same release. Therefore, it is easier and safer in terms of stability (of which fully satisfied dependencies are only part of it) to stick to one release (best to the latest one to avoid issues that have already been fixed) than to mix.